# Failed to start Raise network interfaces. Hyper-V Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hyper-v, ubuntu-16.04

I run a Ubuntu virtual machine inside Hyper-V.
During the launch, an error appears that failed to start networking.

```
osis@projmngsys:~$ sudo systemctl status networking
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Вт 2019-06-18 20:25:45 MSK; 14min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 794 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 778 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --lis
 Main PID: 794 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

июн 18 20:25:44 projmngsys systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
июн 18 20:25:45 projmngsys ifup[794]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
июн 18 20:25:45 projmngsys ifup[794]: Failed to bring up eth0.
июн 18 20:25:45 projmngsys systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
июн 18 20:25:45 projmngsys systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
июн 18 20:25:45 projmngsys systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
июн 18 20:25:45 projmngsys systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

[2]+  Stopped                 sudo systemctl status networking
```

Inside  `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`  i have:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.69
#netmask 255.255.0.0
#gateway 192.168.1.254
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 192.168.1.254
#dns-search google.com
```

In this regard, the question of how to configure Ubuntu and Hyper-V step by step, so that the Internet and SSH work in it.

p.s.

```
osis@projmngsys:~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:64:26:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

--

```
osis@projmngsys:~$ sudo lshw -C network | grep name
       logical name: eth0
```

--

```
osis@projmngsys:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:64:26:04
          inet addr:192.168.1.69  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a00:1370:8125:dfcc:215:5dff:fe64:2604/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fda5:efaf:2260:1:215:5dff:fe64:2604/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe64:2604/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7082 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4055 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1053006 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:4096922 (4.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:203528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:203528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:180782039 (180.7 MB)  TX bytes:180782039 (180.7 MB)
```

--

osis@projmngsys:~$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf - *file clear*

--

```
osis@projmngsys:~$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
```

### ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

```
osis@projmngsys:~$ sudo journalctl -xe
sudo: unable to resolve host projmngsys
-- Результат: failed.
июн 18 21:13:53 projmngsys systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
июн 18 21:13:53 projmngsys systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
июн 18 21:13:53 projmngsys sudo[1813]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys sudo[1921]:     osis : unable to resolve host projmngsys
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys sudo[1921]:     osis : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/osis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start networking
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys sudo[1921]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by osis(uid=0)
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита networking.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита networking.service.
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys ifup[1932]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys ifup[1932]: Failed to bring up eth0.
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys sudo[1921]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита networking.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Произошел сбой юнита networking.service.
--
-- Результат: failed.
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
июн 18 21:13:59 projmngsys systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
июн 18 21:14:11 projmngsys sudo[1995]:     osis : unable to resolve host projmngsys
июн 18 21:14:11 projmngsys sudo[1995]:     osis : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/osis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
июн 18 21:14:11 projmngsys sudo[1995]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by osis(uid=0)
```

--

```
/etc/network/interfaces.d/ - clear
```

Comment: Are there any files in that directory `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`? What are their contents?

Comment: On Hyper-V, do you need to change the NIC model ? I seen that from the hyper-v doc; *Use Hyper-V-specific network adapters, not the legacy network adapter*

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces.d/ - clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several problems at the same time.
Docker left the garbage after deleting, I executed the command:

```
apt remove --purge ubuntu-fan
sudo apt autoremove
```

Next, I cleaned the Samba share file 
removed the mount settings

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Correctly write hostname to file

```
hostname
```

I added the resulting name to the file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

I added host information to the beginning of the file:

```
127.0.0.1 MYHOSTNAME
```

In the file I returned everything to the standard settings

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

I realized that you need to carefully read the text of errors and consistently solve these errors. For this, I read the information in

```
sudo journalctl -xe

sudo systemctl status networking
```

***Read carefully the text of the errors there is a lot of information, thanks to all for the help.***